# Mac OS X driver to work with Linux USB composite gadget driver g_multi

Tags: macos, usb, driver, embedded-linux

I'm interested in using the [Linux USB composite gadget driver `g_multi`](http://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_multi.txt) in an embedded Linux device, for Ethernet-over-USB and serial-over-USB (the Ethernet-over-USB is compiled for RNDIS mode; I'm not interested in the mass storage function, so I've disabled it). I've tested it, and got it working fine with both Windows and Linux. However, brief testing with Mac OS X shows that OS X doesn't automatically load the drivers for it.

I know that in principle OS X has the capability for Ethernet-over-USB, because it works automatically with the Linux USB `g_ether` driver (compiled for RNDIS mode). Likewise OS X works with serial-over-USB with the Linux USB `g_serial` driver—I can connect to the USB serial port with [ZOC](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/screenshotsmac.html). But it does nothing when the Linux device is running `g_multi`.

I can't find any documentation that says how OS X might be made to work with a Linux device running the `g_multi` driver. Has anyone succeeded in doing so?

Can it be done with some sort of simple OS X driver that basically tells OS X to load its drivers for each of the component functions (a bit like the INF files I'm using for Windows, which just tell Windows to load the standard Windows driver for Ethernet- and serial-over-USB)? If so, what is the procedure for doing that?

Comment: Today is 7 years later, in 2020. I run into this problem too. Did you find a way to make it work under Mac with g_multi?

Comment: No, sorry. I never found a solution. Not that I did an exhaustive search. I'm sure there *is* a solution.

Answer (score 1):

RNDIS is unfortunately not supported by MAC OS. You need a 3rd party driver, like https://www.joshuawise.com/horndis.